# How to fix Advanced Evaluator to use Format Locators

Tags: kofax

When I use a Format Locator to find the OrderNr it works fine with 100% confidence on the results, but when I try to use it on Advanced Evaluator and test it with exactly the same Document It doesn't retrive nothing.

[image: Adv Evaluator Config]

Then I try to use a New Format Locator to a different field and I got the exactly the same problem.

This is My test result using Format Locator:
[image: Format Locator Test Results]

This is My test result using Advanced Evaluator:
[image: Advanced Locator Results]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that all dependent locators ran before testing the Advanced Evaluator (AE). You can either process the document (F7), save it, and then execute the AE - in which case KTM will use data stored in the xdoc itself, alternatively you can select `Run All Dependent Locators and Evaluators used as Input for [...]` as shown below.

(I believe that this happens automatically in the most recent releases of KTM)

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your awnser but I'm still getting the same problem(No results only for Format Locators with AE). I'd try all the steps  that you suggest but in the end the results are always empty.

Comment: That's odd. Please get in touch with Kofax Tech Support as this is should work.